# How can I make this tkinter timer get to 0 before it rings?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, countdown

I have a countdown in tkinter made with a label. the function receives an amount of seconds and starts a countdown to zero. When finished, an alarm sounds.

Problem: The alarm sounds at the correct time but the countdown stays at 1 second for a few more seconds before dropping to 0. How could I correct this?

```
def countdown(self, segundos):
    self.guitimer['text'] = f'00:{segundos}'
    if segundos > 0:
        self.after(1000, self.countdown, segundos-1)
    else:
        play(AudioSegment.from_wav("assets/sounds/notification.wav"))
```

Comment: If I remove the -1 it just doesn't count down. If I use segundos >= 0 it gets to 0 but rings 1 second later than it should and after a few seconds the counter drops to -1.

Comment: Most likely, you're playing the sound synchronously, so there's no opportunity for Tkinter to update the label with the final value of zero.  Maybe the `play()` function you're using has some sort of asynchronous option, or you could do one final `.after()` (with a very short duration) to separate the final label update from the sound playback.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks! doing an additional .after() inside a new elif did the trick.

Comment: Add `self.guitimer.update_idletasks()` before `play(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either force update the label before playing the sound:

```py
def countdown(self, segundos):
    self.guitimer['text'] = f'00:{segundos}'
    if segundos > 0:
        self.after(1000, self.countdown, segundos-1)
    else:
        self.guitimer.update_idletasks() # update the label
        play(AudioSegment.from_wav("assets/sounds/notification.wav"))
```

or use `after()` to execute `play(...)`:

```
def countdown(self, segundos):
    self.guitimer['text'] = f'00:{segundos}'
    if segundos > 0:
        self.after(1000, self.countdown, segundos-1)
    else:
        self.after(1, play, AudioSegment.from_wav("assets/sounds/notification.wav"))
```

Comment: Yes! that worked very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to correct it adding an elif for when segundos is 0 and waiting 1 millisecond more to play the sound.

```
def countdown(self, segundos):
    if segundos > 0:
        self.guitimer['text'] = f'00:{segundos}'
        self.after(1000, self.countdown, segundos-1)
    elif segundos == 0:
        self.guitimer['text'] = f'00:{segundos}'
        self.after(1, self.countdown, segundos - 1)
        print('Production time is finished. Extending production time')
    else:
        play(AudioSegment.from_wav("assets/sounds/notification.wav"))
```

Comment: It drops the segundos variable to -1 but keeps the timer label on 0